# Error while converting String with DateTime.ParseExact() function

Tags: c#, datetime, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to convert the string value in the date time. I know this question was asked so many times. But I checked mostly all the answers. But I didn't get answer for my problem.

Following is my code:

```
string ObjTime = "5/4/2013 10:30 PM";

DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(ObjTime, "dd/MM/yyyy H:mm", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

I have also checked by chenging my System datetime format.

And also I have use this:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(ObjTime, "d/M/yyyy H:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Can any one please help me to solve this problem?

And also I have check by changing the format as `d/m/yyy H:mm` but still it is giving me error. I am using `Visual Studio 2012`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string has day and month in single digit, and you are trying to parse it with format which **supports only double digits day/month**

You should do:

```
string ObjTime = "5/4/2013 10:30 PM";
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(ObjTime, "d/M/yyyy h:mm tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

You should use single `d` and `M`, which would support single digit and double digit day/month for parsing.

You should also use **lower case `h`** since you have `PM` in the string. So your final format should be `"d/M/yyyy h:mm tt"`

Comment: I have tried using `d/m/yyy H:mm` Which I have specified in question.

Comment: Your format should be `"d/M/yyyy h:mm tt"` check the updated answer

Comment: @RahulGokani, lower case `h`, not upper case, in your question you have upper case `H`, it should be lower :)

Comment: There is still one thing failing: the "PM" / "AM" should have dots (ie "A.M.").

Comment: @Diego, umm what ? there is no **dot** in the original string `"5/4/2013 10:30 PM"`

Comment: @Habib, I know. It was my culture. I couldn't parse the string as it is in the question. I only was able to parse it adding dots to the string in the question. I changed the culture to `InvariantCulture` and started working. Maybe you should add to your answer that it might work or not depending on the culture.

Comment: @Habib Yes that comment has mistake check the updated question.

Comment: @RahulGokani, in your updated question, you are using `H` (upper case) for hours, since you have time in AM/PM you should use lower case `h`, try the code I have in the answer in visual studio and see if it works

Answer (score 2):

I checked the problem and it seems like your string is not in correct format hence the ParseExact is throwing error.

If you change your string from

```
string ObjTime = "5/4/2013 10:30 PM";
```

to

```
string ObjTime = "05/04/2013 10:30 PM";
```

The code works

Also checked this

[image]

Comment: ParseExact would take the format you specify, one doesn't have to modify the original string

Comment: Right.. thanks @Habib .. But I am saying that the above works.. Mine seems like a way around the problem not the exact perfect solution. Let me check more.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of specifying the format string explicitly, you can try specifying the culture, in which this format is valid. For EN-US culture:

```
  DateTime.Parse(ObjTime, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"));
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can I do that.